# How do you receive packets through TCP sockets without knowing their packet size before receiving?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, video-streaming, aforge

I am working on a network application that can send live video feed asynchronously from one application to another, sort of like Skype. The main issue I am having is that I want to be able to send the frames but not have to know their size each time before receiving.

The way AForge.NET works when handling images is that the size of the current frame will most likely be different than the one before it. The size is not static so I was just wondering if there was a way to achieve this. And, I already tried sending the length first and then the frame, but that is not what I was looking for.

Comment: TCP is a *streaming* protocol. So there isn't anything like *packet size*. (When you read you can't guarantee that it is send as a single packet) So either prefix the packet length or use a separator char/string between packets.

Comment: AForge converts the frame to a RGB24 Bitmap so you are pretty much guranteed that any image will have the same length than the previous one, unless you change camera configuration. But sending the image length as a prefix to the payload is still the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you understand that TCP itself has no concept of "packet" at all, not at the user code level. If one is conceptualizing one's TCP *network* I/O in terms of packets, they are probably getting it wrong.

Now that said, you can impose a packet structure on the TCP stream of bytes. To do that where the packets are not always the same size, you can only transmit the length before the data, or delimit the data in some way, such as wrapping it in a self-describing encoding, or terminating the data in some way.

Note that adding structure around the data (encoding, terminating, whatever) when you're dealing with binary data is fraught with hassles, because binary data usually is required to support *any* combination of bytes. This introduces a need for escaping the data or otherwise being able to flag something that would normally look like a delimiter or terminator, so that it can be treated as binary data instead of some boundary of the data.

Personally, I'd just write a length before the data. It's a simple and commonly used technique. If you still don't want to do it that way, you should be specific and explain *why* you don't, so that your specific scenario can be better understood.

Comment: You're being pedantic. Read RFC 793, it says "The term packet is used generically here to mean the data of one transaction between a host and its network."